# How to filter out noise from non-stationary signal

Tags: filters, python, wavelet, stationary

I have this non-stationary signal.
[image]

the mean is roughly constant but the second moment (autocorrelation) does not depend only on the time lag $tau$.
Correct me if I am wrong in the above statement.

Anyway as you see I have high frequency noise components and I would like to clean it but avoiding any sort of phase lag introduced by a filter.
What can I do to achive my purpose?
I thought of using wavelets to extract the coefficients and then reconstruct the signal, but maybe there is a more efficient and correct way of doing it.

Can you also provide with a link/guide to code this in python?

Comment: [ssqueezepy](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy)

Answer (score 0):

1. Break your signal into short overlapping frames over which it is stationary. Say, the length of the frame is $L$ samples. You can window it to smooth out discontinuities. For example, you can use a Hann window with an overlap of $L/2$ samples.
2. On each windowed frame, use the [Wiener filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter#:%7E:text=In%20signal%20processing%2C%20the%20Wiener,noise%20spectra%2C%20and%20additive%20noise.) to find the optimal inverse filter coefficients to cancel your noise. See `scipy.signal.wiener`.
3. [Overlap add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method) your filtered signal frames to recover the original non-stationary signal.